# How to change dtype of one column in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change dtype of one data frame column (from datetime64 to object).

First of all, I create data frame:

```
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Jan 26 2013, 14:35:25) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> values = pd.Series(i for i in range(5))
>>> dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=5)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'values': values, 'dates': dates})
>>> df
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/config.py:570: DeprecationWarning: height has been deprecated.

  warnings.warn(d.msg, DeprecationWarning)
                dates  values
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00       0
1 2013-01-02 00:00:00       1
2 2013-01-03 00:00:00       2
3 2013-01-04 00:00:00       3
4 2013-01-05 00:00:00       4
```

It have two columns: one is datetime64 and other one is int64 dtype:

```
>>> df.dtypes
dates     datetime64[ns]
values             int64
dtype: object
```

In pandas documentation I found how to convert series to any dtypes. 
It looks like what I need:

```
>>> df['dates'].astype(object)
0    2013-01-01 00:00:00
1    2013-01-02 00:00:00
2    2013-01-03 00:00:00
3    2013-01-04 00:00:00
4    2013-01-05 00:00:00
Name: dates, dtype: object
```

But when I assign this series as dataframe column, I got a datetime64 dtype again.

```
>>> df['dates'] = df['dates'].astype(object)
>>> df.dtypes
dates     datetime64[ns]
values             int64
dtype: object
```

Please, help. How to convert data frame's column to object dtype?
Thanks.

Comment: why are you trying to do this? object representation in the case of a datetime is very inefficient so pandas converts internally.

Comment: I want to convert datetime to object because pandas have a bug (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300730) in pivot totals calculation if column (which used as header) type is datetime.

Comment: the solution in that issue looks fine, just transpose the rows/columns. What you are trying to do has nothing to do with ``datetime64[ns]`` as a dtype and will not help.

Comment: yes, but only if pivot row column isn't datatime too.

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to change from datatype of datetime64[ns] to object, you could run something like this:

```
df['dates'] = df['dates'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
print df.types # Can verify to see that dates prints out as an object
```

Comment: You don't need a lambda in your example, actually: `df['dates'] = df['dates'].apply(str)` would work and read the same.

Comment: This is the right answer. I encountered the same problem when converting a column of int64 to object by using .astype('object'). Printing out column details using .info() shows this column has been converted however the encoding failed saying this columns is not 'str'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert `Date` column which is `object` type to `datetime64[ns] dtype;`, then following code will work:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
In [9]: pd.pivot_table(data=df,rows='columns',cols='rows',values='values',margins=True).T
Out[9]: 
columns  2013-01-01 00:00:00  2013-01-02 00:00:00  2013-01-03 00:00:00  2013-01-04 00:00:00  2013-01-05 00:00:00       All
rows                                                                                                                      
a                          0                  NaN                    2                    3                  NaN  1.666667
b                        NaN                    1                  NaN                  NaN                    4  2.500000
All                        0                    1                    2                    3                    4  2.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Not proficient with lambda usage. In some simple case, `df['dates'].astype(str)` would work also.

**Note:** it doesn't work when there are NaN in a column.

Not solution to OP, but others may find help in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15891038/1278112). Almost duplicate, but it's mostly talk about convert to numeric.