# Using Pandas pd.pivot_table to pivot by date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, pivot-table

I'm still very new to pandas and python, and I'm afraid I'm doing something foolish here.  That said, the closest thing I could find to the problem I'm encountering is here [How to create pivot with totals (margins) in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300730/how-to-create-pivot-with-totals-margins-in-pandas?newreg=6137c12524b84947a79f367bdb56c068), so I am asking.

I've got a simple dataframe with 3 columns.

```
  Account ID Amount Close Date
0         10a    100 2009-01-01
1         10a     50 2009-01-01
2         10a    100 2010-04-01
3         10a    100 2011-04-01
4         10a    100 2012-05-01
..        ...    ...        ...
35         4b     .5 2009-01-01
36         4c     .5 2009-01-01
37         5a     .5 2009-01-01
38         5b     .5 2009-01-01
39         8a     .5 2009-01-01
```

I think I'm having trouble with the close date column.  I suspect that somehow pandas doesn't realize that 2009-01-01 equals another 2009-01-01.

I'd like to pivot this table to get output like this, where I can see things grouped first by account id and then by close date.  If an account id has multiple rows with the same close date, I'd like those amounts to be added up in the values column, like this.  (For the record, I'm really only interested in the year, but in trouble shooting I've been trying to simplify as much as possible.)

```
Account ID Close Date 
2c          2009-01-01  100
            2011-01-01  100
10a         2009-01-01  150
            2010-04-01  100
...
```

I've tried a variety of things, and keep running into problems that make me thing I've got some kind of a date problem.  Maybe I need to import a different library?

Here's my latest attempt:

`pd.pivot_table(opps, index=['Account ID'], columns = 'Close Date', values=['Amount'],  aggfunc=np.su`m)

and the output is very close to what I want.

The only problem is that for any account id that has two rows for a date, that data just disappears in the output.  Account 10a has 3 rows for 2009-01-01, but in the pivot table shows 2009-01-01 Nan.

I thought I'd try the same pivot table with margins = True.

When I did that, I got an error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-f8dc0d75c868> in <module>()
      3                margins = "True",
      4                values=['Amount'],
----> 5                aggfunc=np.sum)

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/pivot.pyc in pivot_table(data, values, index, columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna)
    141     if margins:
    142         table = _add_margins(table, data, values, rows=index,
--> 143                              cols=columns, aggfunc=aggfunc)
    144 
    145     # discard the top level

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/pivot.pyc in _add_margins(table, data, values, rows, cols, aggfunc)
    167 
    168     if values:
--> 169         marginal_result_set = _generate_marginal_results(table, data, values, rows, cols, aggfunc, grand_margin)
    170         if not isinstance(marginal_result_set, tuple):
    171             return marginal_result_set

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/pivot.pyc in _generate_marginal_results(table, data, values, rows, cols, aggfunc, grand_margin)
    236                 # we are going to mutate this, so need to copy!
    237                 piece = piece.copy()
--> 238                 piece[all_key] = margin[key]
    239 
    240                 table_pieces.append(piece)

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1795             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1796         else:
-> 1797             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1798 
   1799     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _getitem_column(self, key)
   1802         # get column
   1803         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 1804             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   1805 
   1806         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionaility

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1082         res = cache.get(item)
   1083         if res is None:
-> 1084             values = self._data.get(item)
   1085             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1086             cache[item] = res

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in get(self, item, fastpath)
   2849 
   2850             if not isnull(item):
-> 2851                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   2852             else:
   2853                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_loc(self, key, method)
   1570         """
   1571         if method is None:
-> 1572             return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
   1573 
   1574         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3824)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3704)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12280)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12231)()

KeyError: Timestamp('2009-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a group by rather than a pivot table to me - your columns are fixed.

For ex.:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['10a', 100, date(2009, 1, 1)],
                        ['10a', 50, date(2009, 1, 1)],
                        ['10a', 100, date(2010, 4, 1)],
                        ['10a', 100, date(2011, 4, 1)],
                        ['10a', 100, date(2012, 5, 1)],
                        ['4b', .5, date(2009, 1, 1)],
                        ['4c', .5, date(2009, 1, 1)],
                        ['5a', .5, date(2009, 1, 1)],
                        ['5b', .5, date(2009, 1, 1)],
                        ['8a', .5, date(2009, 1, 1)]],
                  columns=['Account ID', 'Amount', 'Close Date'])

df.groupby(['Account ID', 'Close Date']).sum()
```

gives:

```
                       Amount
Account ID Close Date        
10a        2009-01-01   150.0
           2010-04-01   100.0
           2011-04-01   100.0
           2012-05-01   100.0
4b         2009-01-01     0.5
4c         2009-01-01     0.5
5a         2009-01-01     0.5
5b         2009-01-01     0.5
8a         2009-01-01     0.5
```

Apologies if I've missed something.

The equivalent with pivot table is:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Account ID', 'Close Date'], values=['Amount'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had experimented with both groupby and pivot_table, and it seemed like pivot_table was closer to the end result I wanted.  I changed something else earlier in my code, and now the pivot table is producing exactly what I want.  Now to figure out why....